# Are <dt> tags depreciated, CSS accordion not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an accordion I built that uses some JS to trigger the open and close. It works fine in my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2rbkg2g/)**, but on the site it does not open. Also it does not throw any errors.

Any Idea on what is causing this? Is the `<dt>` `<dd>` tags depreciated for Google Chrome?

**Javascript:**

```
(function(){
    var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
  touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
  pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

        setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty){
        el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
    };
    setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded){
        switch(expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
                break;
        }
    };
//function
switchAccordion = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if(thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
    };
    for (var i=0,len=accordionToggles.length; i<len; i++) {
        if(touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if(pointerSupported){
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

Also a linke to the **[live-site](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3706857464&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP#accordion3)**, you can see the accordion on screensizes smaller than `1069px`.

It seems to register my click, but doesn't open the accordion.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Run your live site through a validator and fix all of the errors it reports, then see what happens.

Comment: `<dt>` and `<dd>` are not deprecated, no, but they should only be used inside of a `<dl>`

Comment: @Blazemonger They are inside a `<dl>`, so that's good at least. Trying a few things to get it to read this JS.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't want to toggle the `is-expanded` / `is-collapsed` classes.

Comment: Figured this out, the framework does not like to parse JS and prefers to read jQuery.. Rewrote it in jQuery and it seemed to fix it. Please close for "too broad".